# Backgrid.js with Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backgrid

I am using Backgrid for table structure. Now, I have to add action column having edit, view, delete buttons with column Header 'Actions'. I don't get how to do it using Backgrid. 
As we provided one column with one cell so how can I merge more than one cell under one column.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a bit old, so I am not sure if you found an answer.  I am doing something very similar and found that you can extend the Backgrid cell when creating your columns.  Hope this helps!

```
var columns = [
    {
        OTHER COLUMNS GO HERE
    },
    {
        name: 'actions',
        label: 'Actions',
        editable: false,
        sortable: false,
        cell: Backgrid.Cell.extend({
            template: _.template(" TEMPLATE OR HTML GOES HERE "),

            render: function () {
                this.$el.html(this.template());
                return this;
            }
       })
    }
]
```

EDIT: I just added the sortable option, after realizing that sortable defaults to true.  You probably do not want to sort on the actions column.  :)

Comment: How do you bubble click events on the buttons up to the controller for this view?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the accepted answer, while extending the Backgrid.Cell class, it is *very important* to `return this` inside the `render()` function.

Backgrid default `Row` class/object uses cells like this:

```
render: function () {    
  ...
  fragment.appendChild(this.cells[i].render().el);
  ...
}
```

It expects `render()` to be chainable and return the object itself.

So... *Don't forget to `return this;`*